# does attached files move with email or its link is sent in email?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-3.5

I want to do file attachment functionality with an email page. Please guide me on one thing, does attached file is send to recipient email server or it stayed on sender's mail server and its link is send ?

For email if I send email from my hotmail address to gmail address will attached file be physically copied to gmail mail server or just its link (on hotmail ) will be sent and file will remain on hotmail mail server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file data is included in the mail.

Typically the mail is sent as a multi-part message, where the message text is one of the parts, and each attached file is a separate part where the file data is base64-encoded.

Answer (score 3):

Yes attached files move as a copy of the file not a link.  The only way it would be a link is if you just embedded a link in the text of the message.

Eg:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
MailAttachment attachment = new MailAttachment("C:\\SomeFile\\File.txt");
MyMail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

As you can see in the above example that it is attaching a local file and there would be know way to make a link to a local file.